# Как правильно написать предложение?

Tags: пунктуация, орфография, предлоги, окончания

**Во избежании** (или во избежание?) **неловкой ситуации — отсутствия** (или отсутствие?) **свободных мест, просим вас заранее бронировать места по телефону.**

Answer (score 1):

Во избежание неловкой ситуации - отсутствия свободных мест - просим вас заранее бронировать места по телефону.

Производный предлог ВО ИЗБЕЖАНИЕ управляет Р. падежом существительных (чего?).

Второе сочетание "отсутствия свободных мест" **поясняет** первое сочетание "неловкой ситуации" в **добавочном сообщении** и поэтому является **присоединительным** членом предложения (обособление  с помощью тире).

Это **не вставка**, поэтому падежные формы существительных одинаковые.

**ВО ИЗБЕЖАНИЕ** - форма направленного  В. п., поэтому окончание Е (указание на цель).

Answer (score 0):

```
Во избежаниЕ* неловкой ситуации (-) отсутствиЯ**...
```

*Во что, в какое положение мы стремимся войти - *во избежание* (вин. падеж)

**Во избежание чего (вариант с тире); ситуации чего (вариант без тире) - *отсутствия* (род. падеж.)

В другом контексте и при стилистических вольностях возможно такое:

В(о) избежани**и** неловкой ситуации и в отсутстви**и** проблем мы находим успокоение.
В отсутстви**е** проблем мы спокойны даже в присутстви**и** строгого начальства.